# Design pattern for pre-computing lookup tables and "branch prediction"

Tags: c++, events, event-handling, conditional-statements, lookup

I have a program that looks like this:

```
struct EventTypeA {
    int someInt;        // random between 0 and 9
};

struct EventTypeB {
    int someOtherInt;   // random between 0 and 100000
};

int EventAHandler(EventTypeA e) {
    // Updates multiplier
    static int multipler = e.someInt;
    return multiplier;
}

double EventBHandler(EventTypeB e) {
    /* This is a simple example for illustration, the actual intermediate
       calculation takes up much more computational time than this */
    int intermediateResult = (e.someOtherInt * multipler) % 10 + 1;

    if (intermediateResult <= 3) { DoAction1(); }
    if (intermediateResult >= 7) { DoAction2(); }
}

...
...

void SomeMethodWithinSomeClass() {
    while (true) {
        // Listen for events of type A and B
        // if EventTypeA occurs, invoke EventAHandler
        // if EventTypeB occurs, invoke EventBHandler
    } 
}
```

I would like to have `EventAHandler` precompute a lookup table of the `intermediateResult` for all possible `EventTypeB.someOtherInt`'s each time that an `EventTypeA` arrives and I have a new `multiplier`, so I can replace the calculation of `intermediateResult` in `EventBHandler` with a lookup.

The rationale for this is that my `EventBHandler` is time-sensitive, while `EventAHandler` is not: so when an `EventTypeB` arrives later, `EventBHandler` does not have to execute `int intermediateResult = (e.someOtherInt * multipler) % 10 + 1;` (let's pretend this statement takes up a lot more clock cycles) and only has to lookup.

My problem is that it only performs well if `EventTypeA`'s occur frequently while `EventTypeB`'s rarely occur.

At instances when several successive `EventTypeB`'s occur, faster than I can pre-compute the lookup table, I want to kill the precomputation prematurely and switch back to the original approach. Is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have an option of updating your formula for calculating the intermediate results as:

```
intermediate_result = ((e.someOtherInt) % 10) * multiplier + 1
```

Now the first result would be in the range 0-10 and multiplier itself is also in the same range. Now it should be easy for you to have a 10x10 lookup table for the values. Although with the above formula, the actual calculation won't be that sub-optimal itself.

Comment: I gave an upvote for the clever mathematical manipulation, not the final answer I was expecting though because the actual intermediate calculation is much more computationally-expensive than this (something like multiple calls to a linear algebra library and large matrix manipulations). It's my fault for not clarifying this though, so I will update the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may pre-compute once the `0..9 * 0..100000` values.
(You wanted `EventAHandler` does 1/10th of that job each time...)

then `EventBHandler` does just a lookup.
`EventAHandler` won't do the huge computation each time.

If the pre-computated array doesn't fit in memory, you may use a database.

`EventAHandler` unsets a flag when retrieving part of the array and sets a flag when ready.
`EventBHandler` computes the value if flag is not ready, else uses the lookup table.